# Avoid an infinite loop while waiting for user input?

Tags: c++, qt, infinite-loop

I'm caught in a logical catch-22. Let me clarify what I am trying to do: A button press will trigger a motor to move until a sensor is felt (sends 3.3V to my Rpi GPIO), at which point it will reverse direction. This all works fine; the problem is, it is stuck within an infinite loop, so if I want to press another button, for example to increase the speed, or stop it in the middle of a run, well, I can't. 
      I have tried to implement  "wiringPiISR()", as an interrupt, but that seems to also be within a loop to react.

Keep in mind, the following is just a test to get something to work, to be adapted to a much larger piece of code.

```
#include <libraries>


using namespace std;


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->label->setText("Nothing");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;

}

void myInterruptLEFT(void)
{
    qDebug() << "SENSOR HIT";
}


void mainip(void)//this doesn't currently do anything.
{
     wiringPiISR(24,INT_EDGE_RISING,&myInterruptLEFT);

}
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

qDebug() << "Loop Exited";

}

void MainWindow::on_checkBox_clicked(bool checked)
{   int i = 0;
    wiringPiSetupGpio();
    while((checked =! 0))
    {
       ui->label->setNum(i);
       i++;
    }

}
```

So again, I just want some way to have this program constantly checking for "24,INT_EDGE_RISING" ...which for those of you unfamiliar means that there is some voltage being delivered to the 24th GPIO Pin (Rising from low-high volt)...without being completely enthralled by doing so. A background loop, or I really don't know, which is why I'm here. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to do any explicit looping. The event loop already does it for you. You execute actions when certain events happen, e.g. when a button is checked or unchecked.

It'd help to factor out the controller from the UI, and formally specify its behavior using a UML statechart. The code below corresponds 1:1 to the statechart.

[image: Statechart of the Controller]

The `s_moving` composite state has no initial state since it's never entered directly, only implicitly when entering its substates.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/wiringpi-isr-38740702
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <wiringpi.h>

class Controller : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
   QStateMachine m_mach{this};
   QState s_stopped{&m_mach};
   QState s_moving {&m_mach};
   QState s_forward{&s_moving};
   QState s_reverse{&s_moving};
   static QPointer<Controller> m_instance;
   enum { sensorPin = 24, motorPinA = 10, motorPinB = 11 };
   // These methods use digitalWrite() to control the motor
   static void motorForward() {
      digitalWrite(motorPinA, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(motorPinB, LOW);
   }
   static void motorReverse() { /*...*/ }
   static void motorStop() { /*...*/ }
   //
   Q_SIGNAL void toStopped();
   Q_SIGNAL void toForward();
   Q_SIGNAL void toReverse();
   void setupIO() {
      wiringPiSetupSys();
      pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT);
      wiringPiISR(sensorPin, INT_EDGE_RISING, &Controller::sensorHit);
   }
```

The `sensorHit()` interrupt handler is called by the wiringPi library from a high-priority worker thread that waits for GPIO transitions as reported by the kernel. To minimize the latency of reversing the motor, we leverage this thread. Since `sensorHit()` already runs in a high-priority thread and is as close to the GPIO transition as possible, we immediately set the reverse motor direction, and emit a signal to instruct the state machine to transition to the `s_reverse` state. Since this signal is emitted from a thread different than the one the main thread the `Controller` instance lives in, the slot call is queued in the main thread's event queue.

```
   /// This method is safe to be called from any thread.
   static void sensorHit() {
      motorReverse(); // do it right away in the high-priority thread
      emit m_instance->toReverse();
   }
public:
   Controller(QObject * parent = nullptr) : QObject{parent} {
      Q_ASSERT(!m_instance);
      // State Machine Definition
      m_mach.setInitialState(&s_stopped);
      s_stopped.addTransition(this, &Controller::toForward, &s_forward);
      s_moving.addTransition (this, &Controller::toStopped, &s_stopped);
      s_forward.addTransition(this, &Controller::toReverse, &s_reverse);
      s_reverse.addTransition(this, &Controller::toForward, &s_forward);
      connect(&s_stopped, &QState::entered, this, [this]{
         motorStop();
         emit isStopped();
      });
      connect(&s_forward, &QState::entered, this, [this]{
         motorForward();
         emit isForward();
      });
      connect(&s_reverse, &QState::entered, this, [this]{
         motorReverse();
         emit isReverse();
      });
      m_mach.start();
      //
      m_instance = this;
      setupIO();
   }
   Q_SLOT void forward() { emit toForward(); }
   Q_SLOT void stop() {
      motorStop(); // do it right away to ensure we stop ASAP
      emit toStopped();
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void isStopped();
   Q_SIGNAL void isForward();
   Q_SIGNAL void isReverse();
};
QPointer<Controller> Controller::m_instance;
```

The UI is decoupled from the controller: neither UI nor controller objects are directly aware of each other until you link them using `connect`:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   using Q = QObject;
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   Controller ctl;
   QWidget ui;
   QVBoxLayout layout{&ui};
   QLabel state;
   QPushButton move{"Move Forward"};
   QPushButton stop{"Stop"};
   layout.addWidget(&state);
   layout.addWidget(&move);
   layout.addWidget(&stop);
   Q::connect(&ctl, &Controller::isStopped, &state, [&]{ state.setText("Stopped"); });
   Q::connect(&ctl, &Controller::isForward, &state, [&]{ state.setText("Forward"); });
   Q::connect(&ctl, &Controller::isReverse,  &state, [&]{ state.setText("Reverse"); });
   Q::connect(&move, &QPushButton::clicked, &ctl, &Controller::forward);
   Q::connect(&stop, &QPushButton::clicked, &ctl, &Controller::stop);
   ui.show();
   return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

To facilitate testing on desktop platforms, we can add a trivial WiringPi mockup to make it all self-contained:

```
// A rather silly WiringPi mockup
std::function<void()> isr;
int wiringPiSetupSys() { return 0; }
void pinMode(int, int) {}
void digitalWrite(int pin, int value) {
   if (pin == 10 && value == HIGH)
      QTimer::singleShot(1000, isr);
}
int wiringPiISR(int, int, void (*function)()) {
   isr = function;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minor remark: since this method in Controller is static you can use Controller::sensorHit as callback to wiringPiISR, however IMHO adding more motors is really going to complicate your code this way. (As the author mentions "Keep in mind, the following is just a test to get something to work, to be adapted to a much larger piece of code"). You may want to reconsider using a static class method in that case.

Comment: @Elijan9 Unfortunately, the `wiringPiISR` API is broken. Callbacks are not super-useful when you can't pass any user data along to the callback. So you need a separate callback for every pin. That's not a big deal. There is no way to pass custom data into the callback, and anyway since the callback is running in another thread, you can't be directly accessing the `Controller`'s methods since they are not thread-safe. Only the signals are (by design). And that's what we do. So it's all fine. There's nothing to reconsider since the callback **must be** static: it must be castable to a C function

Comment: @Elijan9 I certainly wish you could pass `std::bind(&Class::method, instance)` to `wiringPiISR`, or that one could provide an argument to the callback as is customary in every other non-broken callback API on the planet, but we can't do that. I'll probably fix this deficiency in `wiringPi` soon-ish; the patch is almost shorter than any prose describing it.

Comment: wiringPi is not broken/deficient, it is a C library. The callback does not have to be a static method to your class, it can be a non-class function too. E.g. `void sensor1Callback() { motor1Controller.sensorHit(); };` You can then reuse the controller class for multiple motors and other peripheral, just my 2ct.

Comment: I really appreciate all these suggestions, I'm currently attempting to implement something and see what works.

Comment: @Elijan9 When you design *any* API taking a C callback, you *always* need to pass a `(void*)` along with the callback. This `(void*)` is passed to the callback function every time it's called. This allows reusing one callback for various uses. Typically you'd use it to pass the `this` pointer to an object instance. *Every* sane callback API does that. The absence of this makes `wiringPiISR` objectively deficient. It's like callback 101. You forget that detail and your users will hate you.

Comment: "You can then reuse the controller class for multiple motors and other peripheral, just my 2ct." The controller is specific to one application, obviously, there's no reusing that; it'd need a wholly different design for reuse.

Comment: The idiomatic bridge from a C callback to C++ code, given an API that's not broken, would be: `registerCallback(&MyObject::staticMethod, myObject);`, given `struct MyObject { static void staticMethod(void * arg) { reinterpret_cast<MyObject*>(arg)->method(); }; void method() { ... } };`. This piece of code has been probably written tens of thousands of times all over the world :)

Comment: Please note that he author writes "Keep in mind, the following is just a test to get something to work, to be adapted to a much larger piece of code." Giving something that *is* reusable would definitely help his cause. I did not mean to offend you.

Comment: @Elijan9 We know nothing about the bigger piece of code, so it's best to make no claims as to how one would like to reuse this. Generally, if you wanted a truly hands-off reusable solution that works with current wiringPi, you could use a runtime code generator library to generate executable stubs at runtime, essentially bypassing the broken `wiringPiISR` api. Heck, if you were truly adventurous, you could probably do something like that without using any library, just copying the contents of a function into an executable page and patching a constant in the copy.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I fully understand your problem, but maybe you could model a state machine whith only a single loop that checks all button presses and does all the necessary actions, i.e. your `on_checkBox_clicked` would just set a flag that is then checked in the main loop. Something like this (in pseude code):

```
void MainWindow::on_checkBox_clicked(bool checked) {
    checkBox_wasClicked = true;
}

for (;;) {
    if (checkBox_wasClicked) {
          state = move_motor;
          checkBox_wasClicked = false;
    } else if (motor_reached_end) {
          state = move_motor_reverse;
          motor_reched_end = false;
    } else if ( /*... more transitions ... */ ){
    }

    if ( state == motor_move ) {
         i++;
    }
    /* .... more stuff ... */
}
```

In this way no state blocks the arrival of new buttons presses or other transitions.

Comment: This is not a bad idea. I'd have to figure out how exactly to check for other button presses in qt-creator, but yes, that is more or less the idea. So keep the infinite loop alive, but look out for other actions and prioritize them. Hopefully this is possible!

Comment: @jhizzla Qt Creator is an IDE. You meant "just" Qt :)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you should always use an interrupt when it's available, rather than continuously poll the current state of anything. In that case, a Qt signal needs to be emitted inside the interrupt handler (and you obviously need to have something connected to that Qt signal). Constructed like that you won't need a loop.

There is a minor catch though, for Qt you can only emit a non-static function from a QObject derived class whereas the interrupt handler cannot be part of any class. You could easily solve this by using a pointer to the current MainWindow (there can only be one in Qt) and add a signal to that class, for example:

```
static MainWindow* mainWindow = nullptr;

void ISRSensorDetected()
{
    if (mainWindow)
        emit mainWindow->SensorDetected();
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mainWindow = this;
    wiringPiISR(24, INT_EDGE_RISING,&ISRSensorDetected);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(SensorDetected()), this, SLOT(ReverseMotor()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    mainWindow = nullptr;
}
```

Since you are only using signals and slots an no blocking loop, you can easily handle anything else.

**Note:** WiringPi does not actually use interrupts but creates a separate thread for *every* callback. When using real interrupts you probably should improve on this by using `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(..., Qt::QueuedConnection)` instead to have the interrupt handler return *as soon as possible* and only perform critical operations immediately. The SensorDetected slots will not be called immediately inside the interrupt handler, but will be called later by the Qt main loop. For example:

```
void ISRSensor1Detected()
{
    StopMotor1();
    if (mainWindow)
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(mainWindow, "Sensor1Detected", Qt::QueuedConnection);
}
```

---

In case you really need to use a loop in Qt, you could regularly update the GUI changes by calling `QCoreApplication::instance()->processEvents(QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents)`. But you shouldn't need to in this case.

Comment: This the right approach, generally speaking, except that you really want to reverse the motor direction right in the interrupt callback, before any other code gets to run.

Comment: Note that there's no reason to use an explicit queued connection. The automatic connection will do the right thing: become direct if the signal is emitted in the target's thread, or become queued if the signal is emitted from another thread - as will be the case with wiring Pi ISR callback.

Comment: In that case `emit mainWindows->SensorDetected();` will reverse the motor direction in the interrupt callback. However, IMHO you should always spend as little time in interrupt handlers as possible as other interrupts may occur during the handling. That's why I think queuing is better...

Comment: On the contrary. Your job is to minimize the latency in reacting to the sensor input. Even if this was a real interrupt handler, you'd want to change motor's direction there. Anyway, these aren't "real" interrupt handlers. They are called in userland from a high priority helper thread that gets notified by the kernel through `poll`/`select` syscall.  Switching motor's direction in the high-priority thread is **precisely the right thing to do** to ensure no mechanical damage to the system. Doing motor reversal in the GUI thread would be rather bad.

Comment: Except you may actually be doing GUI updates in the interrupt handler this way and that may actually cause a deadlock. Assuming the Qt main loop is doing nothing, the handling will start immediately after leaving the interrupt handler. In case of preventing hazardous situations, you do not want to use a signal/slot, but instead immediately take action inside the interrupt handler. You will still need to queue the signal if you need to update the GUI accordingly.

Comment: No, you won't be doing any GUI updates in the interrupt handler - how? The only code you should run there obviously is the direction changing one that uses `digitalWrite` function and then signal emission. By emitting a signal in the interrupt handler *after* you reversed the motor, you minimize the latency. The slot call due to signal's emission will be queued automagically.

Comment: Only the directly connected slots are executed immediately. Qt by default uses an automatic connection. Here's how it works: when you emit the signal, the current thread is compared to every receiver's thread, and direct connection is used when they are equal, otherwise a queued connection is used. Qt is designed to help you here, and it does. It's supposed to be easy! By the way, you don't queue the signal invocation, you queue the **slot** invocation. I highly suggest getting a debug Qt built from source and single-stepping into a signal connected to slots in multiple threads.

Comment: Now, since wiringPi does the callback from a worker thread (it couldn't be any other way in fact!), the slots connected to the signal emitted in that thread will be by default invoked via a queued connection. And that's what we all want. Note that since wiringPi does not integrate with any event loops, there's no way for it to invoke callbacks from any preexisting thread, other than by doing very unkosher things like signal injection. It simply runs a thread that listens for pin change notifications and invokes the callbacks ASAP. Simply leverage that when interfacing with Qt.

Comment: The explicit `Qt::QueuedConnection` argument you pass to `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` is unnecessary. You also could also use a pre-looked-up `QMetaMethod`, since the lookup in `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` will do unnecessary memory allocations and other shenanigans every time you use it - in wiringPi's ISR thread you'd like to keep fast, presumably.

Comment: As a general example, using InvokeMethod is better if actual software/hardware interrupts are involved (e.g. automotive), which might interrupt the main loop and cause all slots to be executed immediately before leaving an interrupt handler. So thank you for your feedback on my answer to the author, but I don't see how it would be harmful to use invokeMethod here. Regarding your "it couldn't be any other way in fact!" - it could, using interrupts if supported. If hitting a break-point would always initiate a new worker thread, debugging would be really hard ;)